# Is it possible to ignore J if only one line is selected?

Tags: selection, join

Today I made a macro that involved selecting a few lines to join. The problem was that sometimes I only selected parts of one line and in this case two lines was still joined with `J`. Is it possible to avoid this?

So with which key combination can I do these two transformations: (`<` and `>` indicates selection)

```
content <of line 1
content of> line 2
```

Should be joined like this after pressing `gJ`:

```
content of line 1content of line2
```

And this

```
all <content on> one line
```

Should stay the same after pressing `gJ`. For now it joins the current line with the next one which is not what I want.

Comment: `vnoremap gJ :join!<CR>`

Comment: @Matt Thanks, if you add that as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `:join[!]` command does not really do anything if range has equal start and end values, you can make use of it instead of original `J` / `gJ`

```
xnoremap <silent>J  :join<CR>
xnoremap <silent>gJ :join!<CR>
```

Comment: Please use `xnoremap` instead. See [Why is `vmap` used for both Visual *and* Select mode?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/24895/18609) for details.